# How to get Directory and file name of an image selected from gallery

Tags: java, android, file, path, dir

I need to use this function,

> java.io.File.File(File dir, String name)
>
> public File (File dir, String name)
>
> Added in API level 1  Constructs a new file using the specified
>   directory and name. Parameters dir the directory where the file is
>   stored. name the file's name. Throws NullPointerException if name is
>   null.

Now as we can see it needs file dir and name as parameters. Now I am selecting an Image from gallery by intent. How can I get the dir and name for the selected file.?

Here is the snippet:

```
public File String_to_File(String img_url) {

        try {
            File rootSdDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            **casted_image = new File(rootSdDirectory, "attachment.jpg");**
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            if (casted_image.exists()) {
                casted_image.delete();
            }
            casted_image.createNewFile();

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(casted_image);

            URL url = new URL(img_url);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();

            byte [ ] buffer = new byte [1024];
            int size = 0;
            while ((size = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, size);
            }
            fos.close();
            return casted_image;

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.print(e);
            // e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return casted_image;
    }

    @Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
         super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

         if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
             Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
             String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

             Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                     filePathColumn, null, null, null);
             cursor.moveToFirst();

             int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
             String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
             cursor.close();

             iv.setImageURI(selectedImage);

             // String picturePath contains the path of selected Image
         }
    }
```

What should be done to pass proper parameters to the function in between the lines?

**I am referencing [sharing-text-image-in-twitter-android-example](http://chintankhetiya.wordpress.com/2013/07/18/sharing-text-image-in-twitter-android-example/) . All is good except I want to use my own selected image instead of his URL image. Please help.**

Comment: I am not taking image from URL, I am selecting it from the gallery now. So I need the dir and name of the selected file.

Comment: you have `String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);` this is the path, you can create a class member variable and assign `cursor.getString(columnIndex);` to it. and then access it in `String_to_File(String img_url)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE` option is set on the intent through the `Intent.putExtra()` method:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
```

Your code above should look like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE );
//intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
```

Note: the EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE option is only available in Android API 18 and higher.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE  && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
         filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    casted_image = new File(picturePath);
    cursor.close();
    // String picturePath contains the path of selected Image
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this.

```
File selectedFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File parentDir = selectedFile.getParentFile();

casted_image = new File(parentDir, "attachment.jpg");
```

or if you want to pass selected file's name instead of specific filename. use following line.

```
casted_image = new File(parentDir, selectedFile.getName());
```

you can also check whether selected file is directory or a ordinary file, by using `selectedFile.isFile();`
& `selectedFile.isDirectory();`

Comment: It is showing Pic Upload errorIs a directory. I am referencing http://chintankhetiya.wordpress.com/2013/07/18/sharing-text-image-in-twitter-android-example/ . All is good except I want to use my own selected image instead of his URL image. Please help.